# Clicking link once shows grid, have to click link again to show data in grid?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that when clicked loads a view into the body-content area, as shown here

```
$('#manageusers').click(function () {
    $('.body-content').load("../ManageLoginUsers/ManageUsers");
});
```

and the script for the view getting loaded is this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ShowUserGrid(junkData);
});

// #region Junk Data

var junkData =
   [{
       "UserID": 1,
       "LastName": "Smith",
       "FirstName": "John",
       "City": "Toronto",
       "PostalCode": "N0K 1W0",
       "Phone": "123-456-7890"
   },
   {
       "UserID": 2,
       "LastName": "Doe",
       "FirstName": "Jane",
       "City": "Seaforth",
       "PostalCode": "A1A 1A1",
       "Phone": "519-527-2897"
   }];

// #endregion


// #region Users Grid

function LoadUserGrid() {

}

function ShowUserGrid(userdata) {
    $("#UserGrid").kendoGrid({
        noRecords: {
            template: "No Records Available"
        },
        dataSource: {
            data: userdata
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox', class='check-box' />", template: "<input name='Selected' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>", width: "30px" },
            { title: "UserID", field: "UserID", hidden: true },
            { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
            { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
            { field: "City", title: "City" },
            { field: "PostalCode", title: "PostalCode" },
            { field: "Phone", title: "Phone" }
        ],
        scrollable: true,
        height:700
    });
}

// #endregion
```

Now when the view gets loaded, I see the grid and its empty, so then I have to click the link again and the data gets loaded into the grid.

How can I stop from having to click the link twice to get the data to load into the grid? I have also tried using a button but same thing, and better yet, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fix for the issue, I should have put the junkData in the document.ready.

Once I did then when I loaded the view the grid was populated with the data.